# Is there a list of reserved object names for Rails partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If I have a partial named `_string.erb` and try to render it with something like:

```
= render partial: "string", object: "Some string i want to show in some manner"
```

And then try to reference in my partial with the name `string` it throws the error

```
undefined local variable or method 'string'
```

The only thing I can think of is that the object name is reserved. If something else is going on I would love to hear about it.

Just for clarity, everything works fine for a partial with another name. eg in the partial `dog` rendered with the following code

```
= render partial: "dog", object: "Some string i want to show in some manner"
```

I can reference the variable `dog` without any issues. I am also **NOT** using @string.

I realize I may be able to find this out by digging into the actual source code (which I intend to do after posting this), but if anyone has an idea what is going I would love to hear it. If I find a solution I will post it.

**EDIT** - edited to add the exact error being thrown due to questions about it in the comments.

**EDIT** - I tried to simplify my example when writing this and ultimately ended up proving that string isn't a reserved keyword, and my code was erroring because the value I was passing was nil in the db.

Comment: Is the error `disk not found` or `operating system missing`? If so, then please fix that.

Comment: It throws "an error" is not an easy thing for us to help you with, is there a stack trace we can see to help?

Comment: Sorry, it throws a method missing error, as if the variable isn't defined.

Comment: Specifically: `undefined local variable or method \`string' `

Comment: I just tried rendering a template called _string.html.erb containing <%= string %> just as you called it and it did render properly. I'm on Rails 4.1.4. Could you post the content of the string partial?

Comment: Although, passing `_string.erb` also works.. but it is good to provide format in it i.e  `_string.<format>.erb` eg `_string.html.erb`

Answer (score 1):

There is no official definitive list of reserved words. The list found at https://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/ is the best I've come accross. [String](https://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/words/string?page=7) is included in the list, so very well may be the cause of your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the list. In this case they are referring to the String class, which shouldn't be (and indeed isn't) interfering with my partial rendering correctly. It was just confusion on my part as to how the partial rendered when the object was nil, though I should have expected it to react as it did.

Thanks for trying to help though!

Answer (score 1):

I am 99% sure the source of my error was that my string I was passing in was `nil`. I expected this to return nil to the partial under that variable name `string`, but that doesn't appear to be the case and I just missed it.